# Unable to load module error while running an appengine and gwt project in development mode

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

[image]Please help me rectify this problem. I am not able to run my project in development mode locally, every time I have to upload the project to app-engine to run it.
Terminal output:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution here [Getting errors with GWT tutorial on developers.google.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113169/getting-errors-with-gwt-tutorial-on-developers-google-com) But still no idea how to   set the jvm flag: "-javaagent:/lib/agent/appengine-agent.jar"